# TextBox to Auto-Fill

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

If a user is typing something into a textbox on a form, and what they are typing in starts to match a value that is already in the database, how do I get the textbox to give the option to auto-fill the rest of what the user wants to type in based on the value that is already in the database?

Consider I have this table(name of table: `Person`) in my database:

```
|ID|    |FirstName|    |LastName|
 1        John           Smith
 2        Tom            Jones
 3        James          Davis
```

and on the form where the user wants to create a new `Person` they start to type in *jo* into the `FirstName` textbox.. how do i get the textbox to give the option to autofill the *hn* and capitalize the first letter to spell **John**?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,text,subcategory")] Activity codeAC, string term)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = (from r in db.Activities
                          where r.subcategory.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())
                          select new { r.subcategory }).Distinct();

            db.Activities.Add(codeAC);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(codeAC);
    }
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Activities/Create",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
```

**CSHTML:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subcategory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.subcategory, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "Categories", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subcategory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's an example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/creating-autocomplete-textbox-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5/)

Comment: See [this](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-json-in-mvc.html)

Comment: @BKO so, I was hoping to use this in my *Create* action, but it doesn't work and I think I have followed your reference pretty closely.. do I have to create another JsonResult method for this work?  Can you look over my update to see if you can find any mistakes?

Comment: Acutally yes I did have to create a separate Json method. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I didn't know that I couldn't incorporate this into my *Create* ActionResult.. so I created a separate JsonResult method and it is working.

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteCategory(string term)
{
    var result = (from r in db.Activities
                  where r.subcategory.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper())
                  select new { r.subcategory }).Distinct();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Categories').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Activities/AutoCompleteCategory",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.subcategory, value: item.subcategory };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
})
</script>
```